# OpenCV installlation error ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, opencv, installation

I am trying to install opencv2.2 and after I compile with make command , it build the libraries up to 80% but then fail and give me this error -->

```
../../lib/libopencv_highgui.so.2.2.0: undefined reference to `cvCreateCameraCapture_V4L(int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [bin/opencv_createsamples] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/haartraining/CMakeFiles/opencv_createsamples.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Are there any earlier failures? Does the README or similar guide say you need to install any extra libraries before building the samples?

Comment: I followed the installation guide in OpenCV website and I installed like everything!                                http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/InstallGuide%20:%20Debian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing `cvconfig.h` header sounds like a show-stopper; if you absolutely must continue building from source, you should fix that problem first. (Well, there might be an even *earlier* problem, but missing a header file with such an important-sounding name is likely going to prevent a lot from working.)

But I'm curious why you're not using the standard Ubuntu OpenCV packages, which are already built and have explicit dependencies upon important packages.

If you run `sudo apt-get install libcv2.1 libcv-dev libcvaux2.1 libcvaux-dev libhighgui2.1 libhighgui-dev opencv-doc`, you'll get the libraries, headers, and documentation, installed without any effort to compile the libraries first. Add `python-opencv` to that command if you also want the Python bindings.

Comment: Do you know, how I can solve this problem on Windows Operating System ? I am using Visual Studio 2013

Comment: @AhmetTavli, it'd be best to ask a new question; I haven't myself used Windows since NT 5 beta 2, I'm sure things have changed in the meantime.

Comment: @sarnold Thanks for commenting back, solution is using cmake with visual studio 2012 compiler. OpenCV have Source folder and all you have to do is create compiled version using OpenCV Source folder. This new compiled folder contains cvconfig.h. Actually if anyone needs it, I can mail them.

Answer (score 0):

Check about your V4l/v4l2 drivers, there were problems on these some time ago. 
What do your configure report says? 
Copy/paste the message you got after you do the ./configure

Comment: In file included from /home/OpenCV-2.3.1/build /modules/core/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.cxx:1:0:
/home/OpenCV-2.3.1/modules/core/src/precomp.hpp:52:22: fatal error: cvconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/shamma/OpenCV-2.3.1/build '
make[1]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core_pch_dephelp.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/OpenCV-2.3.1/build '
make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Better edit your question so that we can read the output. And this is not what I was asking for :)